# how to make horizontal dropdown menu with many hierarchy /sub-sub?

Tags: javascript, css, menu

how to make dropdown horizontal menu like in [parkour generation web page](http://www.parkourgenerations.com/) but with sub-sub menu(when i hover the sub menu, ther is appear sub-sub menu with horizontal menu).

in park our, as you can see in classes -> outdoor, there is a sub sub menu but the menu is in vertical. what i need is in the horizontal.

my pleasure if any body knows the tutorial or article to make menu like i need.
i have tried to search but i can't found it

many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is for you

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_drop_line_tabs/

also [see for more](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/)

Comment: mmm, many thanks, i was found it before, but the sub menu in jQuery-Horizontal-Menu is vertical. actually i need the horizontal submenu and horizontal sub-sub menu, :)

Comment: Sorry, i misread your question. see here then  : http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2008/10/creating-horizontal-menu-with-jquery.html  or this one  :http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/561/Horizontal-Sliding-Submenu-jQuery-plugin

Comment: @bungdito..i changed my answer ..see now :)